# Running Sharepoint 2013 farm env. on a 1 tier setup. Need to migrate from 1 tier to 2 tier

Tags: 2013, migration

We are running Sharepoint 2013 on a 1-tier farm setup. I need to change this to a 2-tier setup where the SQL Server 2012 with the DB will be located on its own server and Sharepoint 2013 will be located on the same server as it is now. Basically, I need to migrate the SQL DB from the 1-tier server to a new server and leave Sharepoint where it is.

Can you please aid with this. The web does not seem to have much instructions on Sharepoint 2013.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The process is fairly straightforward:

1. Build your SQL Server 2012 box
2. Take a backup of your SharePoint databases and make the live DBs read-only (or shutdown your SharePoint server to prevent users from updating data)
3. Copy your database files (mdf's & ldf's) from the original box to the new SQL box
4. Restore the copied databases to the new SQL Server and bring them online
5. Create the SQL Alias in cliconfig.exe (both 32 & 64 bit versions) on the SharePoint box
6. Run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard and provide the new SQL Alias
7. Turn your SharePoint web/app server on and it should find the databases in the new location

Here's a good article that outlines the steps:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2012/08/06/install-amp-configure-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-client-alias.aspx

Comment: I've done this for SP2010.  In my process I was able to skip step 6 above because in step 5 I mapped an alias from the 'old' database name to the 'new' database name.  Therefore, all of SharePoint's existing configuration would work as-is.